# Spring @ExceptionHandler does not render view if webapp is restarted in the background

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm dealing with a `HttpSessionRequiredException` and read about (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) how to catch it via the `@ExceptionHandling` annotation.
This does work since my breakpoint hits the spot. Unfortunately the string containing the view name does not trigger any view resolving and therefore no error page is being rendered.

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open `http://localhost:8080/manager` (Session Attributes are being initialized)
2. Restart Web Application (Session/SessionAttributes are being reset)
3. Fill out form and press button (launches POST Request via AJAX - see **Edit #2**)
4. ExceptionHandler jumps in. Since a `HttpSessionRequiredException` is being thrown due the missing session attributes
5. Check Network Panel in Chrome which yields following information on the *failed* POST:

   [image]

   [image]

**Controller Class incl. Exception Handler**

```
@Controller
@Log
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager")
@SessionAttributes({"moduleDescriptors", "Environments", "moduleExecutionData"})
public class ManagerController {

  private static final String MANAGER_VIEW = "manager";
  private final ManagerHelper managerHelper;
  private final ModuleExecution moduleExecution;
  private final SystemProperties SystemProperties;

  @Autowired
  public ManagerController(ManagerHelper managerHelper, ModuleExecution moduleExecution,
                           SystemProperties SystemProperties) {
    this.managerHelper = managerHelper;
    this.moduleExecution = moduleExecution;
    this.SystemProperties = SystemProperties;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public ModelAndView render() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName(MANAGER_VIEW);
    modelAndView.addObject("moduleExecutionData", new ModuleExecutionData());
    List<ModuleDescriptor> moduleDescriptorsFromServices = managerHelper.getModuleDescriptorsFromServices();
    modelAndView.addObject("moduleDescriptors", moduleDescriptorsFromServices);
    //TODO: Change varName for Systems
    modelAndView.addObject("Environments", SystemProperties.getEnvironments());
    log.info("Found " + moduleDescriptorsFromServices.size() + " module descriptors");
    return modelAndView;
  }

  @PostMapping
  public String execute(@ModelAttribute ModuleExecutionData moduleExecutionData) {
    moduleExecution.execute(moduleExecutionData);
//    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return MANAGER_VIEW;
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(HttpSessionRequiredException.class)
  public String sessionError(){
    return "sessionError";
  }

}
```

My view lies within all the folder with all working views.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm configuring spring completely with annotations - not XML.

**Edit**:
I checked the response and saw that it actually returns the HTML of the View. But this HTML is not rendered. Is it because I made a **POST** request? Which actually ignores any return HTML?
But that does not make sense - because my original *PostHandler* does return a view as well and it is rendered.

**PostHandler**

```
@PostMapping
  public String execute(@ModelAttribute ModuleExecutionData moduleExecutionData) {
    moduleExecution.execute(moduleExecutionData);
    return MANAGER_VIEW;
  }
```

**Edit #2**
Here is the POST JavaScript Ajax logic

```
function postForm(event) {
  const moduleId = $(event.currentTarget).data("module-id");
  const formData = $("#" + moduleId).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    url: "/manager",
    dataType: "json"
  });
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you return a `ModelAndView`? There's no reason why it shouldn't work with just the view name though.

Comment: No it did not changed anything. But I found out some new hint. Please read my edit in a few.

Comment: I want to see your full Exception Handler class with all annotation. Please update your question with required information.

Comment: How are you calling the POST method? From ajax?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I added the ajax javascript logic in Edit #2

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I also added some steps to reproduce - which wont work since u guys dont have the classes. But see that I actually keep my browser window open while restarting the webapp in the mean time. Might this cause an issue for rendering returned HTML?

Comment: If you are using ajax calls for your POST method, you should actually return JSON values from your controller method and handle that accordingly in your ajax calls.

Comment: But when I only want to POST form values? As you can see in the `@PostMapping` I use it that way AND it returns a working view. Only the Exception Handler is behaving odd